# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, inversion

When running the code in IDLE gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Python34/inversion3.py",
line 44, in <module>
    nInversions.inversionMergeSort(m)   File "C:/Python34/inversion3.py", line 16, in inversionMergeSort
     left = m[0:half] TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

**CODE:-**

```
from collections import deque

m = []
f = open("IntegerArray.txt")
for line in f:
    m.append(int(line))

class InversionCount:

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def inversionMergeSort(self, m):
        if len(m) <= 1:
            return m
        half = len(m)/2
        left = m[0:half]
        right = m[half:]
        left = self.inversionMergeSort(left)
        right = self.inversionMergeSort(right)
        return self.inversionSort(left, right)

    def inversionSort(self, left, right):
        leftQueue = deque(i for i in left)
        rightQueue = deque(j for j in right)
        orderedList = []
        while len(leftQueue) > 0 or len(rightQueue) > 0:
            if len(leftQueue) > 0 and len(rightQueue) > 0:
                if leftQueue[0] <= rightQueue[0]:
                    orderedList.append(leftQueue[0])
                    leftQueue.popleft()
                else:
                    orderedList.append(rightQueue[0])
                    self.n += len(leftQueue)
                    rightQueue.popleft()
            elif len(leftQueue) > 0:
                orderedList.append(leftQueue[0])
                leftQueue.popleft()
            elif len(rightQueue) > 0:
                orderedList.append(rightQueue[0])
                rightQueue.popleft()
        return orderedList

nInversions = InversionCount(0)
nInversions.inversionMergeSort(m)
print (nInversions.n)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slice indices must be integers or None or have \_\_index\_\_ method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733156/slice-indices-must-be-integers-or-none-or-have-index-method)

Answer (score 40):

In 3.x, int/int gives a float. which is not an int.

```
>>> 3/2
1.5
```

so your line 15

```
        half = len(m)/2
```

makes half a float.  What you need is a double slash

```
        half = len(m)//2
```

to make half an int, as needed for its use in the slice in line 16.

Comment: Able to work, never found to have such a usage before. thank you very much！

Comment: Where can I find it in the python documentation, looking for this operator could not get it.

Comment: The python docs have an index which has a symbols page: https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-Symbols.html.  This page has an entry for '//'. The 'operator' after that links to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-13

Comment: Simple but effective. Nice

Answer (score 7):

In your case, `len(m)/2` returns a `float` and line 16 is expecting an `int`.

You should type cast half to `int` as the following:

```
left = m[0:int(half)]
```

Answer (score 0):

By only using / this will give you result in float you need to use // in order to give the result into integer.

This will resolve the error. It worked for me