# Python2 raises exception when using sorted, but python3 doesnot

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sorting, int

I have a flask application which was deployed to IBM Bluemix Cloud (which runs on Python 2.7). The application was developed using Python 3 and was made backwards compatible using `pasteurize` command. The application (after pasteurize) runs as intended on local machine having Python 3, but on the cloud, the instance, when called, raises the following exception:

```
File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/vcap/app/search.py", line 147, in search
questions_sorted = sorted(question_scores, key=question_scores.get, reverse=True)[:answer_limit]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

`question_scores` is a dictionary having `integer` keys and `float` values. After getting the exception, I have additionally put the keys through `int` method while addition into `question_scores`, but with no luck as the exception is still raised. So, where am I wrong?

Comment: Based on the error message, I guess your problem is with ``answer_limit``. You should provide a [mcve], otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: @MikeScotty the `answer_limit` is an integer

Comment: I would try to use the int method on answer_limit based on the exception message

Comment: @hashark the `answer_limit` is already an integer.

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve]. It's that easy: https://repl.it/repls/PartialBiodegradableCommas

Comment: if you're calculating answer_limit you may have the same issue they describe here which is related to python 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272322/typeerror-slice-indices-must-be-integers-or-none-or-have-an-index-method/28272778

Comment: @MikeScotty I am unable to reproduce the problem using minimal reproducible example, however it seems, the problem just vanished when I replaced the line with: `questions_sorted = sorted(question_scores, key=lambda ind:int(question_scores.get(ind)*10000), reverse=True)[:answer_limit]`, to convert the values of the dictionary from float to integer (only that part was remaining not converted).