# How can I import a specific version of numpy in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

So in my Anaconda environment I have two installed versions of `numpy`. Just for illustration purposes, if I type `conda list` in the Anaconda Prompt, I have the following:

[image]

By default, my Jupyter Notebook uses version `1.20.2`. I have checked this by using:

```py
print(np.__version__)
1.20.2
```

My question is: how can I specifically tell Jupyter Notebook to import version `1.15.4` instead of the default `1.20.2`?
Note: I have tried to adapt to the answers shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912284/how-to-downgrade-numpy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832722/python-select-one-of-multiple-installed-module-versions), but with no luck.

Comment: Hi Marioanzas, How are you doing? I answered your question 6 days ago. Have you seen it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
conda install -c conda-forge numpy=1.15.4
```